# How to automate CMake project with json settings build via MSVS?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, automation

Usual MSVC solutions (.sln) could be build (easily Debug+Release) via MSBuild - just .sln file with configuration key should be passed to the MSBuild.

Now I have CMake project file (CMakeLists.txt) with appropriate settings file (CMakeSettings.json). It is good bunch when using MSVC in manual mode.

But how above cmake build (Debug+Release ++ CMakeSettings.json) could be automated?

Comment: I found the CMake handling on windows (and macos) not sophisticated enough for our build and automation system so we simply removed cmake and went back to solution files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on how it works on VS 2019
If you open a `CMakeLists.txt` file from VS it will try to scan in and uses that with some other files as the project file. It isn't that different compared to standard solutions, just some other files that is used.

[CMake and Visual Studio 2019](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=api&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7116&link=%5B%5B%229F1E006D78894848838A0970E2FF0BE9zoom%22,%22Object1%22,7116%5D,%5B%2271C91DEE3C5A4FDC8EC1114C7C18033Bzoom%22,%22TArticleBook1%22,7116%5D%5D&rows=25)

Comment: There are described how to build solution manually with IDE. In my case I am searching the way how to build it from the command line without IDE. Because I want to automate all builds without any manual work.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in VS2019, the correct way to do this is to use CMakePresets.json and then you can build in a CI using cmake from the cmd.exe. CMakeSettings.json is deprecated. To enabled support for them, there is an option that needs to be enabled. See this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-160 for more information.

tl;dr To build from the command line, do the following:

```
cmake --preset "configurePreset-name"
cmake --build --preset "buildPreset-name"
```